# Stateful Web API service in service fabric in VS 2015 update 2

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric

Currently VS 2015 Update 2 provides an easy way to create owin based stateless web api service using create new service template for service fabric application. Is there a reason why only stateless web api service template is provided and not stateful web api service? If I wanted to, can I modify the stateless web api service to derive from stateful web service? Is it that simple? Or are there any gotchas with this approach?

Comment: Please vote for this feature here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/293901-service-fabric/suggestions/15083877-stateful-web-api-service-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Api is intended to be facade/public entry point to the service fabric app. Being stateless saves the clients from dealing with resolving partitions/addresses and other hassle.

If you want to - you can modify web api service and make it stateful. Maybe it would be even easier to create stateful service from the template, install missing packages (that web api template has), copy `OwinCommunicationListener` and `Startup`, wire them into `CreateServiceReplicaListeners` override, and add valid service endpoint to ServiceManifest.xml. OwinCommunicationListener will provide unique address for each replica.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you certainly can modify it to be stateful. Web API is great for internal service-to-service communication as well as a public-facing API.

There is a caveat that we are currently working through: The web host for stateless uses Kestrel, which presents some difficulties for stateful services where multiple replicas share the same process, because Kestrel doesn't have the same port-sharing capabilities that http.sys-based hosts do. We're working on a solution that makes it easier to use Kestrel for stateful, but in the meantime you can always use the WebListener host, which is the http.sys-based host.

If you're interested, I'm working on a project that will have an ASP.NET Core 1 stateful service (among other cool things) that you can track here: https://github.com/vturecek/service-fabric-xray.

Comment: Can you help me understand why a Stateful web API would even make sense? Chances are it's just a communication layer to a real stateful service so the API wouldn't have any real logic in it.

Comment: i am going to create stateful web api for my project like above. Please let us know any limitation